# Why does Networkxs' path_weight function return integer instead of float?

Tags: python, networkx, weighted-graph

I want to use the function path_weight to calculate the su of weights along a path. The weights are decimals. But the documentation for [path_weight](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.path_weight.html?highlight=path_weight#networkx.classes.function.path_weight) says it would return an int.
The implementation just sums up the weights along the path, and also works for decimals:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edge("a", "b", weight=0.6)
G.add_edge("b", "c", weight=0.2)
sum_path_weights = nx.path_weight(G, ["a", "b", "c"], "weight")
print(sum_path_weights) # Output: 0.8
```

So I am a little alerted to use this function. Does anybody know the deeper reason, why the weights might me decimals but the function wants to return int?

Comment: When you check the source code there is no operation which requires integer value explicitly. I think it is a typo in documentation.

Comment: Thanks, @micro5, for checking the source code. That is what I also assume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comment by @micro5, this can be considered a typo, although the actual reasoning is likely due to the convention of using integers for weights (e.g. a typical example could be that a weight of a link between two nodes is the count of times they exchanged some information).

There is no explicit type-hinting in the source code, so the code will work with both floats and ints. I submitted [PR 5398](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/5398) to update the docs.